# Unable to locate the button

Tags: button, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
<table id="charitiesToAdd" style="width: 100%;">
<div id="newProject000" style="padding-left: 10px; padding-top: 10px;">
<div id="newProject1" class="row row1" style="padding-left: 10px; padding-top: 10px;  clear: both;">
<div class="large-1 columns">
<div class="large-5 name columns" style="font-size: 18px;">Anand's Charity</div>
<div class="city large-5 columns" style="font-size: 16px;">Los Angeles</div>
<div>
<button id="addCharityToProjectButton" class="large-1 columns" onclick="addCharity("newProject1")" style="font-size: 14px;" type="button">Add</button>
</div>
</div>
</table
```

> Above is the html code from which i am trying to locate the button
>   I am having button on my website, at the time of executing with webdriver.
>   It is unable to locate.
>   I have tried with different ways below.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("addCharityToProjectButton")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table/div/div/button[@id='addCharityToProjectButton']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div/div/button[@id='addCharityToProjectButton']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table/tbody/tr/td/div/div/table/tbody/tr[6]/td/input[@id='applyRuleButton']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//button[contains(@onclick, 'Add')]")).click();
```

> Please help me and let me know the correct way to get the solution

I have tried three different types of code for the same,

Comment: Instead of clicking it, just check whether it exists first.

Comment: It is unable to locate the button element. Getting NoSuchElementException and unable to locate the element error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use WebDriver wait to wait for the element to be visible or present i.e DOM and on Screen.

```
 WebElement button = new WebDriverWait(driver,TIME).
 until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("addCharityToProjectButton")));
 button.click();
```

Or

```
  visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("addCharityToProjectButton"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This `By.xpath(//button[text()='Add'])`